# In 1 Timothy 6:6-16 to what does Paul refer when he says "the good confession"?

Tags: referent-identification, 1-timothy

Jesus spoke about the dangers of riches:

> [Mar 10:23 KJV] (23) And Jesus looked round about, and saith unto his disciples, How hardly shall they that have riches enter into the kingdom of God!

When Paul speaks of the dangers, though, he at first seems to speak of the danger "out there" among the baddies that he is encountering:

> [1Ti 6:6-10 ESV] (6) But godliness with contentment is great gain, (7) for we brought nothing into the world, and we cannot take anything out of the world. (8) But if we have food and clothing, with these we will be content. (9) But those who desire to be rich fall into temptation, into a snare, into many senseless and harmful desires that plunge people into ruin and destruction. (10) For the love of money is a root of all kinds of evils. **It is through this craving that some have wandered away from the faith and pierced themselves with many pangs**.

But Paul is warning Timothy. Paul believes he must impress upon Timothy that he must RUN! from the temptation himself because he must be faithful to his confession, THE confession by which he hopes for everlasting life:

> [1Ti 6:11-16 ESV] (11) But as for you, O man of God, flee these things. Pursue righteousness, godliness, faith, love, steadfastness, gentleness. (12) Fight the good fight of the faith. Take hold of the eternal life to which you were called **and about which you made the good confession in the presence of many witnesses**. (13) I charge you in the presence of God, who gives life to all things, and of **Christ Jesus, who in his testimony before Pontius Pilate made the good confession**, (14) to keep the commandment unstained and free from reproach until the appearing of our Lord Jesus Christ, (15) which he will display at the proper time--he who is the blessed and only Sovereign, the King of kings and Lord of lords, (16) **who alone has immortality**, who dwells in unapproachable light, whom no one has ever seen or can see. To him be honor and eternal dominion. Amen.

To what confession is he referring?

Answer (score 4):

This phrase "the good confession" only occurs in 1 Tim 6:12 & 13.  It is recorded as being made by both Timothy in front of many witnesses and By Jesus in front of Pilate.  Since we have no record of such a confession by Timothy, let us examine the confession made by Jesus in front of Pilate.  Such is recorded in Matt 27:11; Luke 23:3; John 18:36, 37 - most fully and completely in the last reference.

> Jesus answered, “My kingdom is not of this world. If My kingdom were
>   of this world, then My servants would be fighting so that I would not
>   be handed over to the Jews; but as it is, My kingdom is not of this
>   realm.” Therefore Pilate said to Him, “So You are a king?” Jesus
>   answered, “You say correctly that I am a king. For this I have been
>   born, and for this I have come into the world, to testify to the
>   truth. Everyone who is of the truth hears My voice.”

From this we find several features about the "Good Confession":

- Jesus is King of His spiritual kingdom, not in the usual worldly sense (compare John 8:23, 14;27, 15:19, 17:14-16)
- Jesus was born into this world (Compare 1 John 4:1-3, 2 John 7)
- Truth is the essence of Jesus (compare John 1:18, 14:6, 16:13, etc)

It was (presumably) these things that were the important elements of Messiah.  Anyone confessing such would thus be confessing the good confession.  On this basis, Timothy made such a good confession either at his baptism or ordination, but that is not recorded.

Comment: So, nothing about "same substance"?   :)

Comment: What do you mean by "same substance"?

Comment: Sorry, "one being with the father" and its variants in the Nicene Creed: http://anglicansonline.org/basics/nicene.html

Comment: OK - I see nothing about "one substance" here at all.  (BTW - I think the "one substance" of the creeds has been a massive distraction and it is unfortunate that it was said at all.  However, I understand their motivation at the time.)